# HtmlWebpackPlugin is not adding charset meta tag

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

HTML Webpack Plugin is not adding `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

However, it says it always does: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/

This is my Webpack configuration:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/')
  }
},
resolveLoader: {
  modules: [
    'node_modules',
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'scripts/webpack/loaders')
  ]
},
entry: './src/index.js',
output: {
  filename: 'dist.js',
  path: path.resolve('www')
},
module: {
  rules: [
    { test: /\.js$/, use: { loader: 'inline-template-loader', query: {} } },
    {
      use: [{
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[path][name].[ext]',
          context: 'src'
        }
      }]
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          options: {
            publicPath: './'
          }
        },
        'css-loader'
      ]
    }
  ]
},
plugins: [
  new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    { from: 'src/static', to: 'static', toType: 'dir' }
  ]),
  new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    { from: 'certificates', to: 'certificates', toType: 'dir' }
  ]),
  new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: '[name].css',
    chunkFilename: '[id].css'
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './src/index.html',
    hash: true,
    meta: {
      'format-detection': 'telephone=no',
      'apple-mobile-web-app-capable': 'yes'
    },
    templateParameters: {
      cordova: env.cordova ? '<script src="cordova.js"></script>' : ''
    }
  })
]
```

Right now, I added the charset meta tag using a variable inside the templateParameters with a reference in the template, also I can added directly on the template. Is there any webpack setting that blocks the automatic charset insertion?

Any help will be really appreciate : )

Comment: I fail to find the docs where it says that meta tags are added automatically.

Comment: Thank you madflow, If you go to the first link provided above and then to *Basic Usage*, there is a screenshot after *This will generate a file dist/index.html containing the following:* where you can see the chartset meta tag : )